Conditional Formatting to highlight a cell green, if other cells in the row are filled in
I wanted to set some conditional formatting on a cell to turn green once other cells in the same row are filled in.
So the aim is to have cell R3 turn green, once cells A3:H3, N3:Q3 are filled in manually.
Below is an image of my excel file:

I have tried to use a new formatting rule; blank cell, ifblank formula. I can't think of a formula that would work.

Use the formula: =AND(A3:H3<>"",N3:Q3<>"")
